# preserving data between rotations using xml layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, preserve

I am Wanting to preserve data when rotating from horizontal to vertical and back again; I know can be done through xml layouts by creating another layout with the same name using -land extension, (activity_main, activity_main-land).

I have no issues with this.

**After rotating my device, the landscape layout comes up as expected. However, the data isn't preserved.**

I have been told that hidden methods will automatically preserve the data between rotations as it will look for a landscape layout and if found, will automatically save the data. I was told that if the two layouts are identically named (activity_main, activity_main-land) the program will consider them to be the same activity and so will preserve the data.

**Is there something else that I should be doing?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

> hidden methods will automatically preserve the data between rotations

No, they won't. You must save and restore data approprietely.

- Usually by overriding onSaveInstanceState you can save data with Bundle object.
- Restoring data from Bundle object in onCreate.

Please refer Google's guide: [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: @Melllvar Sorry, I looked over your edit suggestion. If you edit again, I will approve. Thank you.